# Opera input type="submit" text wrap

Tags: css, button, opera, word-wrap

I have this button on my web-site:

```
<div id="container-div">
    <input class="site-button" type="submit" value="very long text">
</div>
```

with the follow CSS:

```
#container-div .site-button {        
    font-size: 27px;
    height: 100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wDU8w/1/ the text wraps nicely inside the button in all browsers except Opera.

I've tried putting different values into `white-space` and `word-wrap` but with no result.

After some Googling and forum browsing I found that using the `<button>` element instead of `<input type="submit">` would solve my problem. However, I don't want to meddle with the HTML output as it's generated from a PHP script (I'm using a CMS for my site). Is there a CSS way to force Opera wrap the text inside the button?

I'm using Opera 12.15

Comment: It doesn’t look like it is possible. even adding the HTML entity for a line break (&#13;) in the text doesn’t work.  FWIW it doesn't line break in webKit browsers either (at least on Mac) as the button is not getting styled.